# Difference between assert!() and custom Anchor Errors

Tags: anchor, error

What is difference in between

```
#[error_code(offset = 0)]
pub enum CoinFlipError {
    #[msg("Bet Amount small")]
    BetTooSmall, }
```

and

```
assert!(betAmount > minAllowedBet, "Bet Amount small")
```

Please Elaborate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`assert` is a standard Rust macro that will panic if the condition is not met and will crash the program.

`#[error_code]` generates errors that can be *returned* to `anchor_lang::Result`.

I suggest for the code only to panic if there is no other recourse. In most scenarios, you would want to return an Anchor error, preferably with a known error code and message, to make it easier on consumers.